# How to override bootstrap css in GWT Bootstrap 2.3

Tags: gwt-bootstrap

My css are overridden by bootstrap css.

Bootstrap is injecting css after my css.

Is there any why to add my css after injected css.

I know that we can use `!important` to achieve this, But it is not flexible as I need add it to every property.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myapp.com/myapp/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myapp.appspot.com/myapp/css/gwt-bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myapp.appspot.com/myapp/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

is there any way to insert my style sheet after the injected css.

Answer (score 0):

In your gwt.xml check that you add your style sheet file after you inherit the GWT bootstrap module.
The order bellow should fix your issue:

```
<inherits name='com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap' />
<stylesheet src='style.css'/>
```